# How to hide the a tag all rows when table field in database has true

Tags: php, laravel

How to hide the < a # check > all replies when correct field in database has true?
just one true in same post_id

**Database - Replies**

```
...

{
    user_id: 1,
    post_id: 1,
    body: "Lorem ipsum",
    correct: // true or false
}

...
```

**PHP Blade**

```
@foreach ($replies as $reply)
    <li class="item">
        <a href="#" id="check">
            <i class="fa fa-check fa-fw"></i>
        </a>
    </li>
@endforeach
```

I'm sorry if this question is unclear. I'm English not strong. Thanks for every ideas and answers

Answer (score 0):

```
@foreach ($replies as $reply)
    <li class="item">
        <a href="#" id="check">
            @if($reply->correct)
            <i class="fa fa-check fa-fw"></i>
            @else
            <i class="fa fa-times-circle-o fa-fw"></i>
            @endif
        </a>
    </li>
@endforeach
```

Try this

Answer (score 0):

Do you only want to link to correct results (`$reply->correct == true`)?

```
@foreach ($replies as $reply)
<li class="item">
    @if($reply->correct)
    <i class="fa fa-check fa-fw"><a href="#" id="check"></i>
    @else
    <i class="fa fa-check fa-fw"></i>
    @endif
</li>
@endforeach
```